# How to join two special RDDs?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

One is

```
rdd1 : JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String,String>,Integer>
```

another is

```
rdd2 : JavaPairRDD<String,Integer>
```

I want to join rdd1 and rdd2 where Tuple2._1 in rdd1 equals to the key in rdd2.
For example, (("a","b"),1) and ("a",2) will generate (("a","b"),1,2). 
When I map rdd1 to:

```
rdd3 : JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>
```

and try to use rdd3.join(rdd2) , it arose “can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple”.
Is there a solution to join rdd1 and rdd2 and get the results I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map rdd1 to:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<Tuple2<String,String>,Integer>>
```

with something like:

```
x -> new Tuple2(x._1._1, x)
```

use standard join and map once again to have desired result

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry that I tried my thought in python, so led to the error. Transformations in python is different from in java.

Comment: Sure :) I think the same logic should work in Python. `rdd1.map(lambda x: (x[0], x)).join(rdd2)).map(...)`

Comment: You are right. I am so ashamed. Please over look what I said.